# Orange Repositorty

Tags: dataset, repository, orange

KEEL dataset Repository attached link to Orange Repository as a original page of a Marketing dataset  ( http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset.php?cod=163 ). Unfortunately I could not find this dataset there. I need some information about the above mentioned dataset - for example year, when the research took place.

I would be extremely grateful for any help.

Best regards.

Comment: I think for such topics you can get the best guidance at corresponding IRC channels. Checkout #raspberrypi at freenode.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can find more info here: https://github.com/biolab/orange/tree/master/Orange/datasets